# Scan Desktops in a Network

Tags: file, batch-file, networking, desktop

I´m trying to figure out whether it is possible to scan every computer´s desktop on a company wide network for too much or too big files on there. For example:

Search from IP 1.2.3.1 to 1.2.3.99, and if any desktop contains files that are larger than e.g. 20 MB, print that IP to a .txt file.

Would that be possible via batch? Any ideas?

Comment: Every Windows desktop computer in your network will nowadays certainly contain files larger than 20 MB, and 200 MB and even 2 GB.

Comment: Yeah, but I actually meant the user´s Desktop, not a Desktop-PC itself.